# C# Double precision not showing

Tags: c#, double

```
int a=870,b0=-20, b1=120, a0=0, a1=3584;            
double d=(b0 + (b1 - b0) * ((a - a0) / (a1 - a0)));
Console.Write(d);
```

It gives a result as `-20`. I want it precisely upto few decimal places.

whats wrong with c#??

Comment: Make `int` in your first line a `double`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `int`. If you want double precision, convert them to `double` before doing division, or just simply define them as double in the first place. It's doing whole numbers division the way you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing operations between integers thus the result is an integer. Try:

```
double a=870,b0=-20, b1=120, a0=0, a1=3584;            
double d=(b0 + (b1 - b0) * ((a - a0) / (a1 - a0)));
Console.Write(d);
```